# How to fix Assertion failure on PFQuery

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

This simple query of Score (subclass of PFObject)...

```
PFQuery *selfScoresQ = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[Score parseClassName]];
NSArray *selfScores = [selfScoresQ findObjects];
```

returns this Assertion failure...

```
Assertion failure in +[PFObject objectWithClassName:isPointer:]
```

This query is identical to all my others which work fine. I don't know what this assertion failure means or how to fix it. Please help.

ADDITION: interestingly countObjects works

```
[selfScores@ countObjects] // success!
```

Comment: Are you sure "Score" is not nil, and you did implement + (NSString *)parseClassName ?

Comment: Yes...replacing [Score parseClassName] with @"Score" has same result

Comment: Fixed by updating parse framework